# Creating modelform fields for each object in a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, modelform

This question is similar to this: [field choices() as queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104277/)

For example if I have a really simple model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    quantity = models.FloatField()        
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.quantity
```

And the modelform is like so:

```
class OrderForm(models.Modelform):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

Then I have some queryset from another model, ie. I pull the names of all the items:

```
items = [item.name for item in Inventory.objects.all()]
```

How do I generate a quantity field for each item in this list and let the verbose name of each of those fields be the name of the each item? will I need some sort of formset?

Answer (score 0):

```
class OrderForm(models.Modelform):
    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['quantity'].choices = [(i.quantity, i.name) for i in Inventory.objects.all()]
```