# auth select chooses in forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have read this code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104277/field-choices-as-queryset) and look nice.
but if I have user auth and I want user select only your odjects how to change that code ?for ex chooses your personal upload images.

```
from django.forms.widgets import Select
    class ProvinceForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            CHOICES = Province.objects.all()

            model = Province
            fields = ('name',)
            widgets = {
                'name': Select(choices=( (x.id, x.name) for x in CHOICES )),
            }
```

my model :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Comment: So, to understand, you want for each user a `select` dropdown with what? His/her own images? His/her own image names?

Comment: own image yes that upload before in upload form,that work but is no auth example

Comment: @nik_m any idea ?can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you instantiate your form inside your view, you should pass the `user` object, like this `my_form = MyModelForm(user=request.user)`.

Then build your `MyModelForm`:

```
# forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import Select

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # extract "user" value from kwrags (passed through form init). If there's no "user" keyword, just set self.user to an empty string.
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', '')
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.user:
            # generate the choices as (value, display). Display is the one that'll be shown to user, value is the one that'll be sent upon submitting (the "value" attribute of <option>)
            choices = MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.user).values_list('id', 'upload')
            self.fields['upload'].widget = Select(choices=choices)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('upload',)
```

Now, whenever you instantiate the form with a `user` keyword argument (`my_form = MyModelForm(user=request.user)`), this form will be rendered like this (in your template write it like `{{ my_form }}`):

```
<select>
    <option value="the_id_of_the_MyModel_model">upload_name</option>
    <option value="the_id_of_the_MyModel_model">upload_name</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Finally, in order to display images in the dropdown menu (remember, "value" is the one that will be sent back to server upon submiting the form, while the display one just for the UX), take [a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list).

[UPDATE]: How to do it in your `views.py`

```
# views.py

def my_view(request):
    my_form = MyModelForm(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form = MyModelForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            # ['upload'] should be the name of the <select> here, i.e if <select name="whatever"> then this should be "whatever"
            pk = my_form.cleaned_data['upload']
            # image, now, is the value of the option selected (that is, the id of the object)
            obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=pk)
            print(obj.upload.url)  # this should print the image's path
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', {'my_form': my_form})
```

Comment: that `my_form = MyModelForm(user=request.user)` i do in my views.py ?and in the html page ?

Comment: Yes. You do that in your `view`. In your html, simple `{{ my_form }}`. The error you get is because you're using python 2. Change to `super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: i dont understand `'MyModelForm' object has no attribute 'fields'` error my view `def about(request):
    My_form = MyModelForm(user=request.user)

    return render(request,{'Myform':My_form},"about.html")`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was calling `super` at the end. Updated my answer.

Comment: my view `def disaster(request):
    Myform = MyModelForm(user=request.user)

    return render(request,'about.html',{'Myform':Myform})` again replace the super with `super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`? i dont have error but dont show me form in htmal page

Comment: work fine thanks now can you tell me how to get image url from that select form?

Comment: Instead of `choices = MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.user).values_list('id', 'upload')` you can get the each image's url like this: `choices = [(obj.id, obj.upload.url) for obj in MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.user)]`

Comment: that is for form now i need take this request with image in views,για παραδειγμα θελω στο view να παρω με καποιον τροπο αυτη την εικονα που εχει επιλεξει ο user στην φορμα προφανως το paths της γτ στο πεδιο image field `upload` που εχω στο model αποθηκευει τα paths για της εικονες,σωστα ?καλο πασχα χριστος ανεστη

Comment: for example if i have a simple for i use this `form=myform(request.POST or none)` how to do that with our form ?because on view before we use `my_form = MyModelForm(user=request.user)` that confused me