# How to filter a model in django?

Tags: django

So i have a model called Partner. A business is a partner. I have a foreignkey field who takes self as a parameter to create choices. What i want to do is to go through all the created partners and filter out ones that are parent companies. I was thinking of having a boolean that says is_parent. How do i go about this can i search for the boolean in the database and create a choicefield or something with it so i can get a list of parent companies?

What i am trying to do is filter the parents and either make the filtered objects into a choicefiled or make a second model with it so i can offer the choice of selecting the parent.

I have tried to filter through my result but that did not work as expected.

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

from model_utils import Choices
from model_utils.fields import StatusField
from model_utils.models import StatusModel, TimeStampedModel
from phone_field import PhoneField
from addresses.models import Address
from 

common.utils import COUNTRIES





class Industry(models.Model):
    """ Business Industry model """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Industry'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Industries'
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name


class PartnerType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False,
                            help_text="Name of the role or function", max_length=64,
                            verbose_name="Partner Type", )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'partner type'
        verbose_name_plural = 'partner types'

    # TO STRING METHOD
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name


class Partner(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel):

    INVOICE_METHOD_CHOICE = (
        ("PAPER", "Paper"),
        ('EMAIL', 'Email'),
    )

    LEGAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICES = (
        ('CORPORATION', 'Corporation'),
        ('LLC', 'LLC'),
        ('SOLE PROPRIETOR', 'Sole Proprietor'),
        ('PARTNERSHIP', 'Partnership'),
    )

    PARTNER_OFFICE_CHOICES = (
        ('HEADQUARTERS', 'Headquarters'),
        ('DIVISION', 'Division Office'),
        ('SITE', 'Site'),
        ('DC', 'Distribution Center'),
    )

    ADDRESS_TYPES = (
        ('Billing', 'Billing'),
        ('Shipping', 'Shipping'),
        ('Physical', 'Physical'),
    )

    STATUS = Choices('Active', 'Inactive', 'Credit Hold',)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Account Name', )
    office_level = models.CharField(
        choices=PARTNER_OFFICE_CHOICES, max_length=50, blank=True,)
    trade_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Trade Name', )
    logo = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='partners/logos')
    industry = models.ForeignKey(
        Industry,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Industry",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="partners_industry", )
    csp_rank = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True )
    partner_types = models.ManyToManyField(PartnerType)
    account_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, editable=True,default=0)
    vendor_number = models.CharField(blank=True, help_text="TEAZZERS account number with the partner", max_length=20,)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True, null=True, )
    fax = PhoneField(blank=True, null=True, )
    email = models.EmailField('main email address', blank=True)
    ap_email = models.EmailField('AP email address', blank=True)
    ar_email = models.EmailField('AR email address', blank=True)
    website = models.URLField('Website', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    total_units = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Total units',
                                            help_text='How many locations does this organization have?')



    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        help_text="Parent Company name (if necessary)",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        max_length=200
        )
    # if total_units > 0:
    #     status = 'Parent'
    #
    # if status == "Parent":
    #     parent = models.ForeignKey(
    #     'self',
    #     blank=True,
    #     help_text="Parent Company name (if necessary)",
    #     null=True,
    #     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    #     related_name="partners_partner", )

    w9 = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='IRS Form W-9',
                             help_text='Have we received a completed IRS Form W-9?',)
    legal_structure = models.CharField(
        choices=LEGAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICES, max_length=50, blank=True,
        help_text='How is the business structured?',)
    ein = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, default='', verbose_name='Federal Employer Identification Number')
    duns = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, default='', verbose_name='Dun & Bradstreet (DUNS) Number')
    gln = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, default='', verbose_name='GLN (GS1 Global Location Number)')
    insurance = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Insurance',
                                    help_text='Have we received liabilty insurance paperwork?',)
    insurance_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Insurance End Date',
                                          help_text="When does insurance on file end? "
                                                    "Please use the following format: <em>YYYY-MM-DD</em>.")
    insurance_files = models.FileField(upload_to='partners/insurance', blank=True,
                                       verbose_name='Current Insurance Paperwork')
    sales_tax = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Sales Tax Paperwork',
                                    help_text='Have we received Uniform Sales & Use Tax Certificate?',)
    sales_tax_files = models.FileField(upload_to='partners/sales_tax', blank=True,
                                       verbose_name='Current Insurance Paperwork')
    invoice_method = models.CharField(
        choices=INVOICE_METHOD_CHOICE, max_length=64, default='paper')
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Active Since',
                                  help_text="When we begin doing business? Please use the"
                                            " following format: <em>YYYY- 
    MM-DD</em>.")
    address_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=ADDRESS_TYPES,blank=True)
    street1 = models.CharField(
        'Street Line 1', max_length=100, blank=True)
    street2 = models.CharField(
        'Street Line 2', max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=100, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField('Post/Zip-code', max_length=32, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, choices=COUNTRIES, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.city if self.city else ""

        return '%s' % self.full_address

    @property
    def full_address(self):
        return ' %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.street1, self.street2, self.city, 
    self.state, self.postcode)

    def get_complete_address(self):
        address = ""
        if self.street1:
            if address:
                address += ", " + self.street1
            else:
                address += self.street1
        if self.street2:
            if address:
                address += ", " + self.street2
            else:
                address += self.street2
        if self.city:
            if address:
                address += ", " + self.city
            else:
                address += self.city
        if self.state:
            if address:
                address += ", " + self.state
            else:
                address += self.state
        if self.postcode:
            if address:
                address += ", " + self.postcode
            else:
                address += self.postcode
        if self.country:
            if address:
                address += ", " + self.get_country_display()
            else:
                address += self.get_country_display()
        return address

    primary_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Primary Address",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="partners_industry")
    # MANAGERS
    parent_list = list()
    # META CLASS
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'partner'
        verbose_name_plural = 'partners'

    # TO STRING METHOD
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.site_id)

    # SAVE METHOD

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Partner, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.account_number = self.pk + 1000

    # ABSOLUTE URL METHOD
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('partners:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('partners:delete', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some other model (not shown in your `models.py` above) for which you want to only have parent companies be available for selection, first define a callable:

```
parent_companies():
    return Partner.objects.exclude(parent=None).values_list('id', 'name')
```

Then use the callable for `choices=`:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_company = models.ForeignKeyField(Partner, choices=parent_companies())
```

Comment: So am I able to create another model using the contents from this list to give someone the choice of selecting from a dropdown menu?

Comment: Yes, you could have another model that foreign keys to `Partner`:  `partner = models.ForeignKeyField(Partner, ...)`

Comment: If you're talking about restricting the choices for `partner` to just parent companies, then this might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5105092/5548239.  I think that you could make `parent_companies` a callable that returns a set of two-tuples and use this set like so: `partner = models.ForeignKeyField(Partner, choices=parent_companies())`.  I could re-work my answer if this is still not clear.

Comment: Please post the relevant section of your `models.py` rather than just one field from a model.  I can then re-work my answer.

Comment: posted whole model.

Comment: I updated my model please have a look when you can.

Answer (score 0):

this query will get you all the parent companies in all levels 
assume that we have a structure like that

- 1 is parent of 3 and 4
- 2 is a parent of 6 and 5
- 3 is a parent of 9 and 10
- 4 is a parent of 11 and 12
- 6 has no sons
- 5 is a parent of 7 and 8
- 13 has no parent # parent = None

so (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) is a parent as every one has at least one son

```
parents = ModelName.objects.exclude(parent=None).values_list('parent', flat=True).annotate(count = Count('parent')).order_by('parent')
```

this return for you a list of ids for all parents 
you can get queryset of parents as below

```
parents_queryset = ModelName.objects.filter(id__in=list(parents))
```

note : parent means it already have at least one son

if you need to get with them the node which already doesn't have parent # parent is None 
and assume that it have no parent so it is a parent

```
new_parents_queryset = parents_queryset | ModelName.objects.filter(parent=None)
# this queryset is all the parents that have at least one son or the parents that have no parent
```

here (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 13) is the parents as 13 have no parent

Comment: @zef why you need to filter the parents only as any partner have a chance to be a parent 
i think you have to show all available partners in you Partner model